# How to make chrome browser runnning in application mode with selenium when click links to open new tab

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I can run Chrome in application mode using options.add_argument('--app=https:xxx.com') in selenium. However, when i click on a new link within the browser, the newly opened page won't run in application mode. How to solve this issue?I do not want kiosk mode.

Is there any settings in selenium to solve this issue?

Comment: _the newly opened page won't run in application mode_: In which mode does it runs?

Comment: it runs in full screen mode

Answer (score 0):

To open a URL in application mode, you would have to add it as an option as you described.

Thus, to open a link in application mode, it would have to be added to the options first, but you cannot change the options of an already initialized driver, so unfortunately I don't think that this is possible, without knowing the links you are going to click beforehand.

---

The issue of changing the options of an initialized driver has been discussed here:

- Change ChromeOptions in an existing webdriver
- How do I make Chrome Headless after I login manually